# get user permission in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to get the user permissions in sharepoint 2010, the equivalent of this 2013 version:

> /_api/web/lists/getbytitle('')/getusereffectivepermissions

or this:

> http://aissp2013/sites/Team/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('L2')/EffectiveBasePermissions

or something similar to it

Comment: What's the context? Are you constrained to invoking web services remotely or can you use server-side code/Powershell?